# Library for AndroidX same as Glide

Tags: picasso, android-glide, androidx, universal-image-loader

Can anyone let me know about any image loading library for AndroidX that can work the same as Glide? I've searched for other tactics, but nothing is valuable.

```
build.gradle(Module: App)
```

I commented Glide library coz it's not syncing properly.

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-alpha1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha02'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha02'

        //AndroidX
        implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Current version of Glide does work with Androidx. What error you are getting? Provide more details please

Comment: Then what library or code do you use for setting up images?

Comment: Any way or Library same as Glide for Androidx?

Comment: Are you actually looking for `Glide` alternatives or are you not able to set up `Glide`? `Glide` **DOES** work with AndroidX. You might be doing something wrong. Provide some code and error details please

Comment: Oh!OK. 
Actually, androidx is not including Glide dependency in gradle file.

Comment: Oh! it's done after unchecking offline mode.

Comment: File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > OfflineWork (uncheck it). Done! :)

Answer (score 3):

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0' works with androidx
Other : picasso , Fresco are same as Glide(with a little differences) and also UIL(Universal Image Loader).

Comment: if using .... also you need to use latest version of annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:+'

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to build the project on online mode at lease once after adding the library and make it offline, it will solve your issue  and Yes, Glide is work perfectly with AndroidX.